# strange error while working with JasperReports, Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am getting a strange error when trying to print my report.

```
Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GroovySunClassLoader$2 overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Please can anyone suggest what can be the solution for this.

here is the code for printing the jasper report.

```
@RequestMapping("/report")
    public String displayReport(Map<String,Object> map){

        System.out.println("Hello");
        String sourceFileName = "D://jasper"
                + "/report2.jrxml";
        String jasperFileName = "D://jasper"
                + "/report2.jasper";

        List<Project> projectList=projectService.getAllproject();
        String printFileName = null;
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource =
                new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(projectList);

        try{

            // 1. Add report parameters
            HashMap<String, Object> parameters= new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

            parameters.put("ReportTitle", "Project Details");
            parameters.put("Author", "Prepared By Priyanka");

            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(sourceFileName);
            printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jasperFileName,
                    parameters, beanColDataSource);
            if (printFileName != null) {
                /**
                 * 1- export to PDF
                 */
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printFileName,
                        "D://jasper/sample_report.pdf");

                /**
                 * 2- export to HTML
                 */
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(printFileName,
                        "D://jasper/sample_report.html");

                /**
                 * 3- export to Excel sheet
                 */
                JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();

                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.INPUT_FILE_NAME,
                        printFileName);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
                        "D://jasper/sample_report.xls");

                exporter.exportReport();
            }
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "report"; 


    }
```

also the stack trace is as follows:

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Project5] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GroovySunClassLoader$2 overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V] with root cause
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GroovySunClassLoader$2 overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.isCompilable(CallSiteGenerator.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createPojoMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.createCachedMethodSite(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.createPojoMetaMethodSite(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:147)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPojoCallSite(MetaClassImpl.java:2979)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createPojoSite(CallSiteArray.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation.visit(AstBuilderTransformation.groovy:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:799)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:464)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:109)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:201)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:270)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:229)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:539)
    at com.mvc.project.controller.ProjectController.displayReport(ProjectController.java:224)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you please post relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language attribute in the header of your report2.jrxml file is set to groovy, not java.

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
... 
language="groovy" 
...>
```

Change this to

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
... 
language="java" 
...>
```